# How can extended file permissions (ACLs) be managed by Kerberos in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, kerberos

Is it possible to have extended file permissions (ACLs) in Linux be managed (enforced?) by adding permissions authenticated by Kerberos?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will matter, but what Linux flavor/version are you using?

Comment: @NeilSmithline I was going to go for Ubuntu/Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confused. Kerberos is used for authentication, not authorization.
So the answer is no, kind of. You can use Kerberos to authenticate to an account with is authorized, but a Keberos principal alone doesn't qualify as an account.

The most common way to hold accounts in systems that use Kerberos of authentication is LDAP. DQL and `/etc/passwd` also work. These accounts can be used in POSIX ACLs.

If you want to use Kerberos and LDAP, `sssd` currently the preferred client.